# Replace comma with a comma followed by space

Tags: java, regex

Due to the way server-side data is formatted I need to reformat it with my own function and to prevent any unwanted reformatting I want to check if the string I'm reformatting needs to be reformatted.

Here is the condition and the regex involved.

```
String value = "test, test, test.";

if (!value.matches("/(\\s*, )/g")) {
    return value.replaceAll(",", ", ");
}
else {
    return value;
}
```

The expected result is if a string is: `Test,test,test` it will reformat it to `Test, test, test`.

The behavior I am getting is that even the `value` string in the code goes into the `if` condition when it should skip it and go into the `else`.

### Edit after consulting with my reviewer

The best solution found here for me was `",(?! )", ", "` but it solved a problem I didn't even have so I simplified it to `",(\\S)", ", $1"`.

The proposed solution would add a  after `,` even if the `,` would be at the end of the string which is something I didn't want.

Also in my question, I had a redundant `if` condition which I removed and simplified the solution to:

```
String value = "Test,test,test";

return value.replaceAll(",(\\S)", ", $1");
```

**Output:**

`Test, test, test`

Comment: You don't include the `/` and `/g` inside the regex.

Comment: You may also try `return value.replaceAll(",(?! )", ", ")` and remove the `if` condition, it is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to check, you can just use :

```
value = value.replaceAll("\\s*,\\s*", ", ");
```

**Input for example :**

```
test ,   test, test.
```

**Output**

```
test, test, test.
```

Comment: it should be `Test, test, test` as output. use `("\\s*,\\s*", ", ")`

Comment: aah you mean spaces, yes this is my bad @XtremeBaumer i thought the OP want `Test,test,test` ok i fix it thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
result = subject.replaceAll(",([^ ])", ", $1");
```

---

[image]

---

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RqcUix/2)